# C++ RegEx out of memory

Tags: c++, regex, visual-c++

I am using regex to retrieve a string from between divs in a html page however I have run into a out of memory error. I am using Visual Studio 2012 and C++.

The regex expression is `"class=\"ListingDescription\">((.*|\r|\n)*?(?=</div>))"` and regxbuddy reckons it does it in 242 steps (much better than ~5000 it had originally). The website I am trying to scrap the info from is http://www.trademe.co.nz/Browse/Listing.aspx?id=557211466

Here is the code:

```
typedef match_results<const char*> cmatch;
tr1::cmatch results;
try {
    tr1::regex regx("class=\"ListingDescription\">((.*|\\r|\\n)*?(?=</div>))");

    tr1::regex_search(data.c_str(), results, regx);

        cout << result[1];

} 
catch (const std::regex_error& e) {
    std::cout << "regex_error caught: " << e.what() << '\n';
    if (e.code() == std::regex_constants::error_brack) {
        std::cout << "The code was error_brack\n";
       }
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
regex_error caught: regex_error(error_stack): There was insufficient memory to d
etermine whether the regular expression could match the specified character sequ
ence.
```

Regexbuddy works fine and so do some online regex tools just not my code :( Please help

Comment: If you're using VS2012 why not use the regular `<regex>` instead of `<tr1/regex>`

Comment: Probably not useful towards your problem, but is `(.*|\\r|\\n)` any different than `.*`?

Comment: @mah Yes, `.` matches all characters except newline characters.

Comment: Frequently, when grabbing info from inside html it will be easier using a DOM parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a `.` at a place where it can happen multiple times, so it will match all `<`, including the one before `</div>`, which is something you probably do not want.

And now the mandatory link [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) .

Using regexp to parse HTML is *generally* a bad idea. You should use an [HTML parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489522/library-recommendation-c-html-parser) instead

Comment: I see now. Regex is pretty limited in some areas. I will have a look at parsers and try them out. What I have done in the mean time is: 

'
std::string startstr = "<div id=\"ListingDescription_ListingDescription\" class=\"ListingDescription\">";
  unsigned startpos = data.find(startstr) + strlen(startstr.c_str());
  unsigned endpos = data.find("</div>", startpos);
  std::string desc = data.substr (startpos,endpos - startpos); 
'

Answer (score 0):

I see now. Regex is pretty limited in some areas. I will have a look at parsers and try them out. What I have done in the mean time is:

```
std::string startstr = "<div id=\"ListingDescription_ListingDescription\" class=\"ListingDescription\">";
unsigned startpos = data.find(startstr) + strlen(startstr.c_str()); 
unsigned endpos = data.find("</div>",
startpos); 
std::string desc = data.substr (startpos,endpos - startpos);
```

LOL, i know its not great but it works.

Thanks Clement Bellot